# BST isBST() explanation

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

So I found this isBST() function on this site:

```
static struct node *prev = NULL;

bool isBST(struct node* root)
{
    // traverse the tree in inorder fashion and keep track of prev node
    if (root)
    {
        if (!isBST(root->left))
          return false;

        // Allows only distinct valued nodes
        if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data)
          return false;

        prev = root;

        return isBST(root->right);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am having a little bit of trouble following whats going on. Mainly

```
 if (!isBST(root->left))
          return false;
```

and

```
if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data)
              return false;
```

The  `if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data)` seems backwards to me for some reason. I would think it should be  `if (prev != NULL && root->data >= prev->data)` because if the `root->data` was larger then it would be false. I understand that we are doing an in order walk of the tree and checking if it is in order. However, it is what each line is actually doing that is confusing me.

Could somebody please elaborate on what is going on with this function. Thanks

Comment: I implemented `Validate Binary Search Tree` this morning on https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/. This website is awesome, it offers many test cases for you, you can edit and submit code to see the answer. Test cases are simple and small, will help you find the bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the basic idea here is that it starts by descending the tree all the way to the left-most node. That's because the first thing it does as it's called is check that `root` isn't a null pointer, and if it's not null, calls itself recursively on the left sub-tree. When it gets to the left-most node, the `isBST(root->left)` passes in a null pointer, so it returns true. So far, so good.

Then it checks whether `prev` is a null pointer (which, in this first descent into the left-most leaf, it will be). Then it stores the current root into `prev`, and checks the right sub-tree.

In the right sub-tree, it does the same--descends to the far-left node, returns `true` once, and gets back to the last "real" node (i.e. something other than a null pointer). This is where it gets interesting. It gets to the `if` statement, but this time, `prev != NULL`, so it checks that the value in the current node is greater than the value in the node referred to by `prev`.

For example, let's consider a tree like this:

```
        10
      /    \
     4      12
    / \    /  \
   3   5  11   14
```

The first place things get interesting is when it's returned *up* to the `4` node. At this point it sets `prev` to point to the `4` node, then checks the right descendant from there, the `5` node. To be a valid tree, these two have to be in order, so if `root` (current the `5` node) is <= `prev` (currently the 4 node) the tree would be invalid, so it would return false.

When it finishes that, it sets `prev` to point to the `5` node, and checks its right sub-tree (which immediately returns `true`, because it doesn't have a right descendant).

Since that doesn't change `prev`, it's still pointing at the `5` node. So now we return to actual root of the tree, with `prev` pointing at the `5` node, and `root` pointing at the `10` node. Again, if `root` were pointing at a value <= to `prev`, we'd have an invalid tree, so if that happened, we'd return false.

I won't go through all the rest--by this point, I think the pattern is fairly apparent. In particular, every time it looks at the value at `prev`, it's pointing to a node that's to the left of the "current" root, so it requires that the current root be greater than the value at `prev`.

I believe this can be cleaned up (quite a bit) though. I really dislike using a `static` here, among other things. At the very least, this should be passed as an extra parameter instead of using a static variable.

Comment: Wow. This definitely made it a lot clearer and simpler. Now, I may be getting ahead of myself, but for curiosity sake, how efficient is this recursive call? As far as performance wise?

Comment: @Bryan: at least with most modern compilers/hardware, it's quite efficient. The branches are fairly predictable, and most recent hardware caches return addresses from recent calls. I'd also note that the original had essentially the same recursive calls, so it's unlikely to differ between the two.

Comment: Your solution is *incorrect*. "The value in the left descendant is less than the value in the current node." - This is a must, but it's not enough. You want to compare the value with the rightmost value in the left *subtree*. The whole point of the original design is that it does an in-order traversal and it checks the constraint for each neighbour. And it's a really nice design. Fix the ugly static variable (for multithreaded apps) and it's perfect.

Comment: As for the performance, the cost of the recursive calls is quite negligible compared to cache misses caused by the node-like structure. If your tree is relatively small, a custom allocator might help ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I've edited (replaced) the answer to be accurate (I believe). If you could re-check, I'd appreciate it though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, any time if we see a contradiction we can immediately return `false` - think of it as a short-circuiting. The rest of the tree is irrelevant at that point.

The two `isBST` calls are simple part of the recursion for the in-order walk.

As we go in-order, the values are strictly increasing (no duplicates). So if we see a mismatch, we can return false, so this is the right condition:

```
root->data <= prev->data
```

---

I couldn't format an example in the comments so I left here one showing where @JerryCoffin's solution will fail:

```
    3
   / \ 
  2   5
 / \
1   4
```

Comment: E.g.: we saw 5 (prev), now we see 4 (root). The 5 comes from the left subtree which has *smaller* values. That's a contradiction, this is not a BST. `return false`.

Comment: Btw. BST does not have a defined order, it can be chosen either way. You just need to be consistent. IMO having a part of state outside of recursion in a static is a quite bad idea, it kinda kills the recursion making it iterative, and needlessly hard to understand. Lastly the thing that hasn't been touched, `prev != NULL` part is for handling left-most leaf.

Comment: The `static` thing can be rewritten as a passed parameter with an extra level of indirection (reference or pointer)